# Why doesn't GetMethodID() return NULL on non-existing method?

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

So the documentation on [GetMethodID()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) says this:

> Returns a method ID, or NULL if the specified method cannot be found.

On Android, however, this doesn't seem to be the case because calling `GetMethodID()` with a non-existing method name always throws a fatal exception and kills the whole thread. Consider this code:

```
jmethodID id = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, mActivityClass, "iDontExist", "()V");
```

This results in a complete thread crash and the following output on Logcat:

```
01-26 15:11:30.210  6403  6507 F art     : art/runtime/thread.cc:1657] No pending exception expected: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/example/test/TestActivity;.iDontExist()V"
01-26 15:11:30.210  6403  6507 F art     : art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at void com.example.test.TestActivity.nativeRunTest(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) ((null):-2)
01-26 15:11:30.210  6403  6507 F art     : art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at void com.example.test.TestMain.run() ((null):-1)
01-26 15:11:30.210  6403  6507 F art     : art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:761)
01-26 15:11:30.210  6403  6507 F art     : art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]
01-26 15:11:30.253  6403  6507 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
01-26 15:11:30.253  6403  6507 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
01-26 15:11:30.253  6403  6507 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "TestThread" prio=5 tid=14 Runnable
... lots of lines indicating a crash follow ...
```

Isn't this behaviour a violation of the JNI specification which clearly says that `GetMethodID()` should return `NULL` if the specified method cannot be found?

If this is really intended behaviour, is there any other way to find out from C code if a Java method exists?

Comment: In terms of whether or not this is intended, it's unlikely that anyone here can answer. Create a test project that demonstrates the problem, then file a bug report. I don't see any existing bugs referring to this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that it is this specific line in the JNI code where this is occurring? I have never written any JNI code; but the documentation says that you should be checking for exceptions after method calls, and the source code of art looks like it prints this message if there is a pre-existing exception when you try to throw another exception

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your question where you have demonstrated that `GetMethodID` didn't return `NULL`. What you _have_ demonstrated is that you cannot ignore Java exceptions thrown by JNI functions. After any call to a JNI function that may throw a Java exception you must deal with those exceptions, e.g. by using `ExceptionCheck` and `ExceptionClear`. When I try to reproduce this, the result I get is that an exception is thrown _and_ `NULL` is returned. @forpas's deleted answer is the correct one IMO, except that it doesn't mention how to handle the exceptions.

Comment: You two are right, `GetMethodID()` indeed returned `NULL` and the crash occurred later. So if I add the line `if((*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);` right after the `GetMethodID()` call it works as expected and nothing crashes any more. So one of you might want to post this as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetMethodID` *does* return `NULL` in this case. However, it also throws a `NoSuchMethodError` exception:

> **THROWS:**
>   `NoSuchMethodError`: if the specified method cannot be found.

It is an error to call [most `JNIEnv` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp17626) - or to try to return back to Java<sup>*</sup> - while there's a pending exception thrown by a JNI function. Note that these exceptions are not C++ exceptions, so even in C++ you can't use `try`/`catch` to catch them. And in C that would obviously not be an option anyway.

The `JNIEnv` provides you with the following methods to handle these exceptions:

```
ExceptionOccurred
ExceptionDescribe
ExceptionClear
```

So in this particular case where you probably don't really care about the exception, the following code would be enough to handle it:

```
if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
    (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
}
```

These kinds of checks needs to be done after every JNI call that could throw an exception.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Unless you catch the exeption at the Java side.</sub>